# Inserting htm text into sqlite database

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I am given lots of files with htm format (which can be read by web browsers in windows) with lots of text lines in each. I wanna put them in sqlite database line by line . Is there any way to parse this kind of file to insert it to database ? In the attached picture you can see one of htm files opened by firefox . Tnx in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can parse `HTML` and insert it into a `sqlite3` database as text with a simple `INSERT` command. Depending on the language in question there are various HTML parsers and sqlite connectors. In general you want to get the line or element that you want and then run this command with the correct variables on the database: `INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> VALUES (<value1,value2,value3,...valueN>);` with one of the values being the HTML text you with to insert into its column.